# Python 'subprocess' gets stuck after cx_Freeze

Tags: python, subprocess, cx-freeze

I run subprocess in python with timeout like that. If Timeout occurs -> then kill the process. It works great when run like python script, but after making .exe via cx_Freeze, the whole application stucks forever. What could be wrong?

```
      try:
            process = subprocess.Popen(
            [
                'STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe',
                '-c',
                'port=SWD',
                'freq=4000',
            ],
            text = True,shell=True, cwd=self.cubeProgPath,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


      except e:
            try:
                os.kill(process.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
            except:
                pass
            
            return False
        
        # now chek if timeout occured - if yes - kill the process
        while True:
            if process.poll() is not None:
                #process is done
                res = True
                break
            
            elif (time.time()-stamp) > myTimeout:
                #timeout occured
                os.kill(process.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
          
                break
```

Comment: This isn't strictly related to your problem, but generally, one uses `shell=True` _or_ passes arguments as a list, not both. It's not immediately breaking you here because you're on Windows, and the rules are different, but the code you're using right now wouldn't work at all on MacOS or Linux.

Comment: for Linux I know this does not work, so there I have different version.  So soulution could be set shell=False ?!

Comment: No, as I said the comment wasn't related to (and thus wasn't an attempt to fix) your problem. If I had an answer I was confident in, I'd be adding an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

last time I used cx_Freeze, I used threading so my application would not crash or freeze.

Steps:

1. Convert your code to OOP
2. Bind the thread to **init**()
3. Implement run() function in which you place your script's driving code

In your constructor:

```
import threading
# Class inherits from threading.Thread
class App(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        # Bind threading.Thread to __init__
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        pass
```

In your main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

Comment: Actually my app is threading APP. But I do not want to get my thread stucks forever. Maybe I do not understand your thoughts.. .